# AngularJS $digest already in progress When Calling JavaScript Native Bridge Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, native

I am using AngularJS 1.4.8, running in a QT webview control.

The scenario is:

1. I make a $http/$resource call. While that $http call is in progress
2. I call a JavaScript to native bridge function which in this case
   downloads a PDF and prints via a USB thermal printer.
3. I return from the native call and execute another $http request before the first one has finished.
4. I then get the message `[$rootScope:inprog]$digest already in progress`

I am not calling $apply/$digest.

I did not write the QT C++ code for the JS-native bridge functions so I am not familiar with the nature of that code or why it would cause angular to call $apply/$digest again on the second $http request.

I prefer not to use something like $$phase to guard against this.

Is there any way to guard against this from the web application side in a global/generic way that does not require me tracking promise states pre-post making the native call(s) each place it is called?

Comment: this doesn't make any sense;  `$http` doesn't do anything to the `$digest`...

Comment: If you dig into the source as I have, you will  notice that it does increment a counter for the digest cycle and sets $$phase=$digest.  In fact, protractor waits on $digest and $http to complete before checking expectations based on this.

Comment: you found this in the `$http` source?  where?  I'm not finding any reference to `$digest` in `http.js`, and I've never heard that `$http` would affect `$digest`;  it is designed to return a promise, not modify the DOM.

Comment: OK.  I'm going to walk that comment back.  My recollection was incorrect.  It only seems to inc/dec a counter for the benefit of protractor.  I'm not clear on why the digest issue would happen.

Comment: When $http resolves using $q, $q.resolve triggers the digest
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13108